# kotlin async/await: send multiple GET requests and await for the results later downstream

Tags: kotlin, async-await

I am trying to send multiple GET requests to the server but await for the results as it comes in like the code below:

```
suspend fun getRequests(value: Int): Int {
    val rnd = (100..3000L).random()
    println("Delay for $rnd")  // simulate network time delay.
    delay(rnd)

    return value * 2
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val myList: ArrayList<Deferred<Int>> = ArrayList()
            for (i in 1..10) {
                println("GET request sent: no$i")
                myList.add(async {
                    getRequests(i)
                })
            }
            myList.forEach {
                println(it.await())  // process the results
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a `delay` in the `getRequests` to simulate network latency. My objective is to `await` for the result as it comes in and process it. However, from what I can tell in the results printed out to console (as below), it is being processed sequentially...

```
GET request sent: no1
GET request sent: no2
GET request sent: no3
GET request sent: no4
GET request sent: no5
GET request sent: no6
GET request sent: no7
Delay for 706
Delay for 487
Delay for 2894
Delay for 1857
Delay for 353
GET request sent: no8
Delay for 2216
GET request sent: no9
Delay for 546
GET request sent: no10
Delay for 1806
Delay for 1291
Delay for 2830
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

How should I do it such that the results can be processed the moment it comes in, and not wait for results sequentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```kotlin
myList.forEach {
    println(it.await())  // process the results
}
```

You are waiting for the responses sequentially, i.e. you first `await` for the first `Deffered` to complete then the next one and so on. Instead if you want to process the responses as they arrive, you should do that in the `async` block itself. And when you do that, you will realize that its better to use `launch` instead of `async` because there is no value to return.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        for (i in 1..10) {
            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val result = getRequests(i)
                println(result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/onKtP_fxS)

Sample output:

```
Delay for 1 -> 1447
Delay for 2 -> 2370
Delay for 3 -> 861
Delay for 5 -> 1156
Delay for 4 -> 973
Delay for 6 -> 827
Delay for 7 -> 1975
Delay for 8 -> 2560
Delay for 9 -> 2850
Delay for 10 -> 1989
12
6
8
10
2
14
20
4
16
18
```

Here you can see that first value printed is 12 because the delay for 6 was minimum (827), next 6 is printed because 3 has the next higher delay (861) and so on...

Comment: thanks. so the idea is to set the loop before the launch of the async items. cool!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need the result as list, since there is `myList` in your sample code, the other solution is

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        (1..10).toList()
            .map { 
                async {
                    getRequests(it)
                } 
            }
            .awaitAll()
            .forEach {
                println(it)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kenny. i tested this and it seems pretty good as well. :)